# Prestashop Main Menu Module

Tags: module, prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.7

I'm using the module provided by Prestashop but when I add the 'Home' shop category it doesn't link to the page where it lists all the products. Is there a way to link to the top parent category while it still having children?

Comment: Which version of prestashop are you using?

Comment: 1.7, is that the reason why? It seems like I must have to create a root category and insert them all inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home category use this link:
`www.mysite.com/2-home`

This link works only in PrestaShop >= 1.7.x.x
In PrestaShop 1.6 is not "navigable"

If you want to link the home category from the module use a custom link and not the category that you find in the (multi)select